# Generating one string out of 3 input fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 3 input fields (firstname, midname, lastname) that I have created using v-for for each client. Every time client name changes, I want to generate an updated version of the name in an object as a string.

```
<input :data-index="index" data-field="first-name" @keyup="nameUpdated">
<input :data-index="index" data-field="middle-name" @keyup="nameUpdated">
<input :data-index="index" data-field="last-name" @keyup="nameUpdated">
```

This is the method I though of, where index is the client count. But then I thought that is not the right way to achieve it. How I thought about it was on nameUpdated function, store client firstname, midname and lastname as an object and then reorganize it like:

`client[1][first-name]' + ' ' + client[1][middle-name]' + ' ' + client[1][last-name]'`

What is the right way of achieving a task like this?

Comment: Use a computed property https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: So you are saying store it as an object like `client[1][firstname]: John, client[1]lastname]: Doe` etc and use computed property on every component which I will call it?

Comment: Or you can use a watcher to manually update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computed property is more than enough to do the trick.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clientList: [{
      firstName: 'John',
      midName: '.',
      lastName: 'Doe'
    }]
  },
  computed: {
    fullList() {
      return this.clientList
        .map((client) => `${client.firstName} ${client.midName} ${client.lastName}`)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addList(){
      this.clientList.push({
        firstName: '',
        midName: '',
        lastName: ''
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Client List
  <button v-on:click="addList()">Add</button>
  <table>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Middle Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <tr v-for="client in clientList">
      <td><input type="text" v-model="client.firstName"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="client.midName"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="client.lastName"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
    <div>Result</div>
    <div>{{fullList}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```